# Can Model-specific questions be asked here?

Tags: discussion

I'm working on a personal project and having a difficult time working out the model to develop the database for it. I was going to just ask my question here when I realized that it might considered 'off-topic' so I thought I would ask?

If a user was developing a model concept for a project could they ask for assistance in best practices leaning towards their project here?

Comment: yes, but you'd have to be careful to ask questions that are not 'too broad'